# $.getJSON with PHP Post returning null. Hardcoding the variables returns properly

Tags: jquery, json, post, null, jsonp

I have a bit of a problem executing a JSON query to a local file. When I use;

```
<script>
$('.Import').on('click', function(){
    $.getJSON("charFetch.php?name=" + $('.charname').val() + "&realm=" + $('.realmname').val(),function(data){

        console.log("charFetch.php?name=" + $('.charName').val() + "&realm=" + $('.realmName').val());
        console.log(data);

    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

In conjunction with;

```
//$realmName = $_GET['realm'];
//$charName = $_GET['name']
```

In my PHP file, it returns null. However when I actually load the PHP file directly with those two variables posted in my browser it prints out the jQuery as usual, and if I hardcode in the $realmName and $charName variables, I get a valid return in the console.

This is very confusing, I'd greatly appreciate any and all help.

I've tried adding things like "&callback=?" so it gets treated as JSONP, but since I'm pretty much clueless in this area I'm just grasping at straws.

**Edit**
A suggested fix in the comments has fixed it returning null, thank you!

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: Also, dunno if it helps, but why not use `$.getJSON('charFetch.php',{name:$('.charname').val(),realm:$('.realm').val()},function(){...});`

Comment: `charFetch.php?name=Reglitch&realm=Turalyon localhost:17
 
null`

Argh, trying to get the formatting right, but the null is on a new line.

Comment: Ah, adding your suggested code fixed it. Completely foreign territory for me right now, I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @TimWithers: Can you put that down as an answer? @OP, it doesn't work because the parameters must be percentile-encoded. Google for `encodeURIComponent(..)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the jQuery.getJSON syntax for the reason Thrustmaster said, in that it will encode the text appropriately for the request:

```
$.getJSON('charFetch.php',
    {name:$('.charname').val(),realm:$('.realm').val()},
    f‌​unction(){...});
```